# Node js npm is giving error message when creating an init

Tags: node.js, npm

I keep getting an error message from node js when I try to initialize a package for json (which it says cannot be found in any directory). I can only use this as a sample of the error message since the text won't appear on my command prompt.

```
    npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "init"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
npm ERR! path C:\package.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\package.json']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\package.json' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "init"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
npm ERR! path C:\npm-debug.log.f816ae1c7bf9f7d432028592d95d82cf
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\npm-debug.log.f816ae1c7bf9f7d432028592d95d82cf'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\npm-debug.log.f816ae1c7bf9f7d432028592d95d82cf']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\npm-debug.log.f816ae1c7bf9f7d432028592d95d82cf' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log
```

Is there something going wrong with my system that is causing this, or do I need to reinstall node js? By the way, I am the root administrator.

Comment: Just place the file in a non-system folder so that you won't need permission to run it. Documents folder will do the job

Comment: May be you do not have file permissions to write on C:\ drive root. Try in a sub folder.

Comment: I thought that may be the case, but I am the only user on my system. I also have the ability to allow applications to run as an administrator as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running cmd as Administrator. Right-click cmd.exe and select Run as Administrator and execute your command again.

Answer (score 0):

Running the console with administrator permission and retry the command